# react useEffect is running and fetching data none stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple react component that uses react hooks.  I'm using useEffect and useState.
The problem is that i realized my API is getting huge amount of hits, after debugging i see that useEffect is running none stop!

This is my very simple code:

```
function DisplayUser({userId}) {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(userId).then(user => {
      setLoggedUser(user);
    })
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{loggedUser}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whats happening here is that `useEffect` is running [after each render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update...

There is a way to do [Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects), you can pass an array as a second argument.

If the array is empty, that means there are no "dependencies" for this effect and it will run only once (quite simillar to `componentDidMount`).

If the array has values, then the effect will re-run only when those values have changeded (simillar to what we do with `componentDidUpdate`).

So in your case it is wise to pass an array with the `userId` value because you'll want to re-run the effect and fetch the user data only when the `userId` has changed.

```
function DisplayUser({userId}) {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(userId).then(user => {
      setLoggedUser(user);
    })
  }, [userId]); // only run when userId changed
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{loggedUser}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```